# PHP Get peak from dataset with value and timestamp

Tags: php, dataset

I need to get the peak from a dataset using PHP. This dataset is made with timestamp and value. I need to get the 3 peak like the image with the 3 relative timestamp

This is a graphic rappresentation of the dataset:
[image]

But i don't need to rappresentate graphically, i'd like just a simple return of an array of the three value/timestamp. I need also a sort of threshold for avoid flase positive peak, for example minimum variation like from 0 to 400 (i'll define it in case but i need a threshold)

You can find the example dataset here:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d7d20a726285ea29ae2ff682764b045020210401192032/13e788

Many thanks for the help, i'm stuck with this. I have searched on Stackoverflow, i have see some algorithm but i cant apply to my necessity

Comment: Post a text example of dataset.

Comment: Given the large number of records or readings, is there any chance that you first import them into a (maybe temporary) database table? If so then the task is relatively simple and I can help.

Comment: AbraCadaver i have posted it, there is a link of a JSON. Stefanov.sm i can use MySQL 5, i prefer the PHP way but I'm opened to alternative solution. I don't who downvoted the post, I was clear and I have add all the necessary information...

Answer (score 0):

I think that your sample data size suggests a database as a proper tool for the job. So assuming that data is already stored in table `readings` with two numeric columns - `ts` and `reading`, then this query may help.

```sql
select ts, reading 
  from
  (
    select ts, reading, lag(reading) over (order by ts) as variation from readings
  ) as t
 where variation < 400 -- or whatever your threshold value may be
 order by reading desc 
 limit 3;
```

This is Postgresql dialect that I am most comfortable with. You can re-write it in another SQL dialect if necessary and then easily pull the result data in PHP using PDO for example.

Comment: I don't have LAG function since my MySQL version doesn't support it, but thanks anyway for the attempt

Comment: It will be hard to filter false positives by variation w/o window functions. Pls. note that you may use SQLite that is a small shared object or DLL that doesn't require installation. It supports `lag` and PHP PDO and will do the job. I think that the above query will work under SQLite.